# iPhone iOS how to initialize GCD dispatch timer with a specific fire time?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I'm looking to start the timer in the code below at a specific time and cannot find a way of  instantiating `dispatch_time_t` with the time I want. I'm particularly not sure how to get `mach_absolute_time` to initialize the delay.

I saw some answers on how to initialize dispatch_time_t after a certain delay:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

Which is not what I need.

Here's what I want to do:

- Get current time in milliseconds.
- Get rid of the milliseconds part.
- Add one second
- Add 20 milliseconds.
- create `dispatch_time_t` with that time
- Pass it to the timer

**This way I want my timer to start firing predictably at every second + 20 milliseconds and repeat at predictable times. How can I accomplish that?**

Here's my current dispatch timer code

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.eeg.bgqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    synchronizeTimer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
//I want to specify when the timer will fire
    dispatch_source_set_timer(synchronizeTimer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_MSEC * updateIntervalms/2.0, NSEC_PER_MSEC * 0);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(synchronizeTimer, ^
                                      {

                                             // do your processing here
                                           [activeConnection sendNetworkPacketThreadSafe:[circularArray objectAtIndex:lastArrayIndex]];



                                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a wallclock-based timer and not a `mach_absolute_time`-based timer.

See the manpage for `dispatch_walltime(3)`, that takes a `struct timespec` base time that you can configure with your requirements based on the result of `gettimeofday(2)`.